# Поиск файла в директории установленой через set_include_path

Tags: php

```
$flag=fopen(realpath(dirname(__FILE__) ).'\pub\\'.'magic.txt','rb')
```

-вот так файл получаю.
Теперь хочу чтобы файлы можно было получать с директории

```
set_include_path('realpath(dirname(__FILE__) )'.'\pub\\');

$flag=fopen('magic.txt','rb')
```

``ошибка **No such file or directory**

Comment: "**из** директории". всегда ваши граммар наци.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Из мана:

```
resource fopen ( string $filename , string $mode [, bool $use_include_path = false [, resource $context ]] )
```

следовательно

```
$flag=fopen('magic.txt','rb',true);
```

и у вас там кавычки, т.е. надо:

```
set_include_path(realpath(dirname(__FILE__) )'.PATH_SEPARATOR .'pub'); 
//лучше добавить а не переписать include_path:
//set_include_path(get_include_path().PATH_SEPARATOR.realpath(dirname(__FILE__)).PATH_SEPARATOR .'pub');
$flag=fopen('magic.txt','rb',true);
```

но вообще так лучше не делать - медленно. лучше путь добавлять к имени:

```
$path=realpath(dirname(__FILE__) ).PATH_SEPARATOR .'pub'.PATH_SEPARATOR;
$flag=fopen(path.'magic.txt','rb');
```

Comment: Благодарен.Убрал кавычки и заработало.